# How to get all available hostnames and associated IP addresses on LAN using Obj C on Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c

I have a requirement to get the list of IP addresses of all the machines connected to LAN. I created an NSHost object and used it to get addresses of current host and it worked fine. But I need to get addresses of all other hosts on the network. 
Any helpful answer would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

my snippet:

```
NSHost* host = [NSHost currentHost];
NSString* myIPAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                  [[host addresses] objectAtIndex:1]];
```

executing this gave myIPAddress as 192.168.1.202 which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That's not necessarily knowable, and depends on collusion with the other hosts. You might consider determining your broadcast address (e.g. 192.168.1.255), sending an ICMP echo request and then enumerating the responses: but a system that doesn't respond to the request won't show up. Similar problems are apparent when using responses to any other request: port scans or mDNS registrations.

Comment: Thanks Lee, that works. but have been wondering if we have any specific class or framework in obj-C which serves the network operations like the one mentioned.

Comment: @Balaji did u get the solution?